# index value of the tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

write a function named sums that takes 3 arguments: 2 lists of integers nums1 and nums2, and an integer target; then return a tuple containing indices i and j of the two numbers in nums1 and nums2, respectively, where the numbers at that indices add up to target (i.e, nums1[i] + num2[j] = target). If there is no solution, return “Not found”. The function sums must contain exactly only one loop (either a for-loop or a while-loop), otherwise you will get no point. A nested-loop is considered as more than one loop.

```
def sums(nums1, nums2, target):
nums1 = [11, 2, 15, 7, 8]
nums2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
target_number = 9
for i in range(len(nums1)):
    for j in range(len(nums2)):
        total = nums1[i] + nums2[j]
        if total == target:
            a = (nums1[i], nums2[j])
            print(a)
```

This is the code that i have written and i am struggling to get the index values can anyone please  help!

Comment: Note that your homework instructions say that you can only use one loop. Note also that you are instructed to **return** your result, not print it.

Comment: What does it mean that the function should only have **one** loop? Can you use hidden loops, like `itertools.product`?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "struggling to get the index values"? Do you mean you are struggling to get the right answer?

Comment: @mozway you could do this with a while loop and two "pointers".

Comment: Basically you are asking us the solution of your competitive programming question, I don't think StackOverflow was created for this purpose. :)

Comment: when i run the code i get (7,2) which is the correct answer but i need the index value of that and i have used the index() which resulted in none

Comment: First, can you please fix your indentation? Right now it looks like you are overwriting the `nums1` and `nums2` parameters. Second, you are setting `a = nums1[i], nums2[j]`... you just need `i` and `j`.

Comment: Again though, you are not completing the question correctly according to the instructions, which specify that you only use one loop.

Comment: @ddejohn not sure what you mean by "*two pointers*" (I'd be interested to see the answer), I used a dictionary and a single loop to check for the difference to target ;)

Comment: Ah, yeah that's a better solution lol. The "two pointer" method is actually just a hack in this case -- as I understand it it's usually applied to a single list, not two different ones. You have one "fast" pointer that advances every loop while one "slow" pointer stays fixed until some condition is met. Using it here is just a hacky way of getting around the one loop constraint. In general though, the two pointer technique can be useful in some contexts.

Comment: @mozway "two pointers" solution is up :)

Comment: @ddejohn I see, flattened iteration, nice one (although quadratic) thanks ;)

Comment: Yep. It's not great lol. Applicable in some contexts, but not so great here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in O(n) with a dictionary and a single for loop;

```
nums1 = [11, 2, 15, 7, 8]
nums2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
target_number = 9

def sums(nums1, nums2, target):
    d = dict(zip(nums2, range(len(nums2))))
    for i,n in enumerate(nums1):
        remainder = target-n
        if remainder in d:
            return (i, d[remainder])
    return 'Not found'

sums(nums1, nums2, target_number)
```

Output: `(3, 0)`

Be aware that while there is a single `for` loop, the code is looping to construct the dictionary, it's just not visible directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using basic index incrementing. It's not as efficient as using a dictionary and finding the difference, as this naively iterates over `b` as many times as there are items in `a`. In the worst case, with two equal-length lists, this solution is `O(n^2)`.

Although it may actually be faster in smaller cases, if there happens to be a bottlneck around the creation of any of the intermediate data structures that @mozway uses. I'm only speculating on this, I don't actually know.

```py
def target_sum_idxs(a, b, target):
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(a):
        if a[i] + b[j] == target:
            return i, j
        j += 1
        if j == len(b):
            i += 1
            j = 0
    return "Not found"
```

Demo:

```py
>>> target_sum_idxs(nums1, nums2, target=9)
(3, 0)

>>> target_sum_idxs(nums2, nums1, target=9)
(0, 3)

>>> target_sum_idxs(nums1, nums2, target=999)
'Not found'
```

Answer (score -1):

just one little thing.

Check that the variable in the `if` statement is really your parameter, not the `"target_number"` variable.
Also, in the `if` statement, you need to stop execution, maybe you can use a break or return the tuple.

I would use something like this:

```
def sums(nums1, nums2, target):
    for i in range(len(nums1)):
        for j in range(len(nums2)):
            total = nums1[i] + nums2[j]
            if total == target:
                a = (i, j)
                return a
                
    return "Not found"
```

Comment: Note that `a` needs to be set to the tuple `(i, j)`, not `(nums1[i], nums2[j])`, since OP needs the indices, not the values located at those indices.

Comment: This however doesn't meet the requirement to use only a **single** loop ;)  "*The function sums must contain exactly only one loop (either a for-loop or a while-loop), otherwise you will get no point.*"